# cordova + ionic = how to disable default scroll ios and keyboard pushing div

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

hello i would like to no let keyboard in ios push element to the top like it do. And disable the keyboard with cordova.plugins.Keyboard.close();

But it seems not working

I followed many solutions but it seems not working

my build info

Xcode 8.1
Build version 8B62
cordova 6.4.0
ionic 2.1.14
iphone 6 real device

thanks for helping me!

login controller :

```
vm.isLoggedIn = function () {
  if (authFactory.isLoggedIn) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};

vm.login = function () {
  if (vm.user.login && vm.user.password) {
    vm.isLoading = true
    var user = {
      login: vm.user.login,
      password: vm.user.password
    };
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: ENV.apiEndpoint + '/login',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      data: user
    }).then(function (response) {
      if (response.data.token) {
        $window.sessionStorage.token = response.data.token;
        authFactory.userProfile(response.data.account);
        authFactory.isLoggedIn = true;
      }
      vm.isLoading = false;
      $state.go('dashboard');
    }).catch(function (error) {
      toaster.pop({
        type: 'error',
        title: 'Erreur',
        body: 'Password/login incorrect',
        showCloseButton: true
      });
      vm.isLoading = false
    });
  } else {
    toaster.pop({
      type: 'error',
      title: 'Erreur',
      body: 'Password/login manquant',
      showCloseButton: true
    });
  }
};

  vm.clearInput = function (inputName) {
    if (inputName == "password")
      vm.user.password = '';
    else if (inputName == "login")
      vm.user.login = '';
  };

  vm.clearIdentifiant = function () {
    vm.identifiant = '';
  };

  if(ionic.Platform.isAndroid()){
    $(document).click(function (e) {
      if (e.target.nodeName != "INPUT") {
        $("#header").show('fast');
      } else {
        $("#header").hide('fast');
      }
    });
  }

  $("#but-send").on('touch', function(e) {
   ionic.plugins.Keyboard.close();
   console.log(ionic.plugins.Keyboard);
 });
}
```

}

login.scss:

```
.keyboard-open {
  transition: opacity 0.2s 1s;
}
```

login template

```
<ion-view id="home" scroll="false" overflow-scroll="false">
 <div id="header">
  <img ng-src="img/logo_esynergy.png" class="logo">
  <p class="text-center">eSynergy</p>
 </div>
 <form ng-submit="home.login()" id="formConnect">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col col-80 col-offset-10">
    <span class="item item-input item-floating-label">
    <span class="input-label"><i class="icon ion-person placeholder-                      icon"></i> Identifiant</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Identifiant" ng-model="home.user.login" id="login" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" >
    <button type="button" ng-if="home.user.login"
            class="input-button button button-icon ion-close-round"
            ng-click="home.clearInput('login')">
    </button>
  </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-80 col-offset-10">
  <span class="item item-input item-floating-label">
    <span class="input-label"><i class="icon ion-key placeholder-icon"></i>Mot de passe</span>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Mot de passe" ng-model="home.user.password" id="password" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" >
    <button type="button" ng-if="home.user.password"
            class="input-button button button-icon ion-close-round"
            ng-click="home.clearInput('password')">
    </button>
  </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col text-center">
    <button type="submit"
            class="button button-medium button-positive"
            ng-disabled="home.isLoading"
            id="#but-send">
      <span ng-if="!home.isLoading">Connexion</span>
      <span ng-if="home.isLoading">En cours...</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

and finally my config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example.helloflorent" version="1.0.0"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<name>blank</name>
<description>
    A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
</description>
<author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
    Apache Cordova Team
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
<chcp>
    <config-file url="http://localhost:31284/chcp.json" />
    <local-development enabled="true" />
</chcp>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
<plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="~2.2.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.1.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~4.0.0" />
```